# Can ASP.NET Core 3.0 support GRPC and HTTP endpoint in one application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application. I want to have 2 endpoints in my application, 1 for HTTP and 1 for GRPC.

Can I have them in the same process using `app.UseEndpoints()`?

Comment: In theory it sounds like it should be possible. Precisely how you do it, I'm not entirely sure I can help you there sorry.

Comment: You can, as long as you ensure your controllers/pages/API and gRPC mapping don't conflict. The section [Add gRPC services to an ASP.NET Core app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#add-grpc-services-to-an-aspnet-core-app) simply adds `AddGrpc()` and `endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();` to an existing application. Have you tried this? Did you encounter a problem?

Comment: How do you plan on distinguish the one receive connection from the other?  Do you plan on using different port numbers?

Comment: @jdweng yes I will use 2 different port numers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried this and encounter some problems.  But it seems there  are some bugs in my code,  I will try it again later.

Comment: There is no reason two endpoints can be in the same process. especially if the use asynchronous methods.

Comment: @jdweng I guess you mean "There is no reason two endpoints can NOT be in the same process" ?